# vuex-persistedstate: How can I use getters with vuex-persistedstate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I use [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate). But getters doesn't work.
I checked state in Vue.js Devtools, state was present. But getters didn't have data. Like this.

[Vue.js Devtools in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSuw1.png)

So how can I use getters?

**index.js in Vuex**

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    login,
    segments,
    itemList,
    orderList
  },
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState()
  ]
})
```

**index.js in vue-router (I want to use getters for login status check)**

```
import store from '@/store'

Vue.use(Router)

const ifAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
  if (store.getters.loginStatus) {
    next()
  } else {
    next({
      path: '/login',
      query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
    })
  }
}
```

**login.js (store module in Vuex)**

```
const state = {
  loginStatus: false,
  email: '',
  isStaff: false,
  company: '',
  token: ''
}
const getters = {
  loginStatus: () => state.loginStatus,
  email: () => state.email,
  isStaff: () => state.isStaff,
  company: () => state.company,
  token: () => state.token
}
```

Comment: Can you include your getters code?

Comment: Yes. I added getters code in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're accessing outside `state` object. Please try to add `state` as function parameter:

```
   const getters = {
      loginStatus: (state) => state.loginStatus,
      email: (state) => state.email,
      isStaff: (state) => state.isStaff,
      company: (state) => state.company,
      token: (state) => state.token
    }
```

Comment: It works! I forgot parameter... Thank you very much for your speedy answer!